# Django:"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" on get_queryset function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am getting

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded on the below code

```
class BookingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Booking.objects.all()
serializer_class = BookingSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return queryset
```

I found that the problem is with the `get_queryset` function, but i can't find what is its cause.

Comment: my mistake. that is the issue. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `get_queryset()` inside `get_queryset()`, so clearly that is going to be an infinite recursion.

You should probably reference just `self.queryset` instead:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return queryset
```

although you might as well leave out the class-level definition altogether and just do it in the method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Booking.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return queryset
```